# How To Make Last Visited Viewcontroller The RootViewController?

Tags: objective-c, uiviewcontroller, nsuserdefaults, uistoryboard, appdelegate

I figured it out. Thanks shim for the info!:

```
UIViewController* vc = (UIViewController*)[[UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"iPhone4" bundle:nil] instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"MyViewControllerIdentifier"];

if ([[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"currentViewController"] isEqualToString:@"iPhone4Level1"])
{
    [self.window setRootViewController: vc];
}
```

Comment: Give more details on the crash. Where does it occur, what does it say, etc.

Comment: But is my code correct? @shim

Comment: @shim see my edits for the NSLog

Comment: It's good that you updated your question, but you really shouldn't delete your question in case future visitors want to figure out what you were asking about and what you tried that wasn't working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't initialize a class via `NSClassFromString`. It doesn't return an instance of the class, it returns a Class object. This is an Objective C feature that helps identify classes. This is why you're getting this error, since the variable you're trying to set as the root view controller is not a view controller and thus cannot respond to the view controller methods. Classes are initialized using their own initializers

e.g.

```
MyViewController* vc = [[MyViewController alloc] init];
```

Or if you're using nibs/storyboards, using other initializers:

```
MyViewController* vc = [[MyViewController alloc] initWithNibName: @"myNib" bundle: nil];
```

or

```
MyViewController* vc = (MyViewController*)[[UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"MyStoryboard" bundle:nil] instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"MyViewControllerIdentifier"];
```

To do what you're trying to accomplish, you'll need some logic to figure out what class to load based on the class that was saved.

e.g.

```
Class c = NSSClassFromString(@"MyClass"
if ([MyViewController class] == c) {
   //load MyViewController, e.g. using init or instantiate from storyboard etc
}
else if ([MyOtherViewController class] == c){
   //load MyOtherViewController
}
//etc
```

However, you might be better off defining a few values as identifiers (integers, strings, whatever you want) and saving those instead of the class names, since classes can  be subclassed, re-used, etc. You probably also wouldn't want every single view controller class in the app to be a permissible starting point. Then you could avoid this `NSClassFromString` business and just do a simple switch statement or logical expression.

Comment: Where in my project would I put 'MyViewController* vc = [[MyViewController alloc] initWithNibName: @"myNib" bundle: nil];'

Comment: Would I put this code in AppDelegate. I'm really confused.

Comment: Same place, just instead of UIViewController *controller = (UIViewController *)NSClassFromString(savedClassName);

Comment: please look at my edits. I tried your code in app delegate but it still opens to the first view. What did I do wrong?

Comment: Do you actually have a storyboard set up with that identifier on the view controller?

Comment: Yes my Storyboard ID is MyViewControllerIdentifier

Comment: I have another problem relating to the topic please look at the edits. I'm sure you'd know how to fix this.

Comment: Sometimes you have to let people sweat a bit.

Comment: I'm really confused please help.

Comment: I figured that out too!